# Why is this Rust program so slow? Did I miss something?

Tags: rust

I read *[Minimal distance in Manhattan metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183668/minimal-distance-in-manhattan-metric/39186417)* and rewrote the author's "naive" implementation in [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_%28programming_language%29). The C++ variant is:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

std::pair<int, int> pointsA[1000001];
std::pair<int, int> pointsB[1000001];

int main() {
    int n, t;
    unsigned long long dist;

    scanf("%d", &t);

    while(t-->0) {
        dist = 4000000000LL;
        scanf("%d", &n);

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scanf("%d%d", &pointsA[i].first, &pointsA[i].second);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scanf("%d%d", &pointsB[i].first, &pointsB[i].second);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < n ;i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < n ; j++) {
                if(abs(pointsA[i].first - pointsB[j].first) + abs(pointsA[i].second - pointsB[j].second) < dist)
                    dist = abs(pointsA[i].first - pointsB[j].first) + abs(pointsA[i].second - pointsB[j].second);
            }
        }
        printf("%lld\n", dist);
    }
}
```

The Rust variant is:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::BufRead;

fn read_array(stdin: &mut BufReader<io::Stdin>, array_len: usize, points: &mut Vec<(i32, i32)>) {
    let mut line = String::new();
    for _ in 0..array_len {
        line.clear();
        stdin.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
        let mut item = line.split_whitespace();
        let x = item.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap();
        let y = item.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap();
        points.push((x, y));
    }
}

fn manhattan_dist(a: &(i32, i32), b: &(i32, i32)) -> u32 {
    ((a.0 - b.0).abs() + (a.1 - b.1).abs()) as u32
}

fn main() {
    let mut line = String::new();
    let mut stdin = BufReader::new(io::stdin());
    stdin.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
    let n_iters = line.trim_right().parse::<usize>().unwrap();
    let mut points_a = Vec::with_capacity(10000);
    let mut points_b = Vec::with_capacity(10000);
    for _ in 0..n_iters {
        line.clear();
        stdin.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
        let set_len = line.trim_right().parse::<usize>().unwrap();
        points_a.clear();
        points_b.clear();
        read_array(&mut stdin, set_len, &mut points_a);
        read_array(&mut stdin, set_len, &mut points_b);
        let mut dist = u32::max_value();
        for i in points_a.iter() {
            for j in points_b.iter() {
                dist = std::cmp::min(manhattan_dist(i, j), dist);
            }
        }
        println!("{}", dist);
    }
}
```

Then, I generated data with a Python script:

```py
import random

ITER = 100
N = 10000
MAX_INT = 1000000

print("%d" % ITER)

for _ in range(0, ITER):
    print("%d" % N)
    for _ in range(0, N):
        print(random.randrange(-MAX_INT, MAX_INT + 1), random.randrange(1, MAX_INT + 1))
    for _ in range(0, N):
        print(random.randrange(-MAX_INT, MAX_INT + 1), random.randrange(-MAX_INT, 0))
```

And compiled both variants with `g++ -Ofast -march=native` and `rustc -C opt-level=3` respectively. The timings are:

**C++**

```
real    0m7.789s
user    0m7.760s
sys     0m0.020s
```

**Rust**

```
real    0m28.589s
user    0m28.570s
sys     0m0.010s
```

Why is my Rust code four times slower than the C++ variant? I am using Rust 1.12.0-beta.1.

I added time measurements:

```
let now = SystemTime::now();
line.clear();
stdin.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
let set_len = line.trim_right().parse::<usize>().unwrap();
points_a.clear();
points_b.clear();
read_array(&mut stdin, set_len, &mut points_a);
read_array(&mut stdin, set_len, &mut points_b);
io_time += now.elapsed().unwrap();

let now = SystemTime::now();
let mut dist = u32::max_value();
for i in points_a.iter() {
    for j in points_b.iter() {
        dist = std::cmp::min(manhattan_dist(i, j), dist);
    }
}
calc_time += now.elapsed().unwrap();
```

And `writeln!(&mut std::io::stderr(), "io_time: {}, calc_time: {}", io_time.as_secs(), calc_time.as_secs()).unwrap();` prints `io_time: 0, calc_time: 27`.

I tried nightly `rustc 1.13.0-nightly (e9bc1bac8 2016-08-24)`:

```
$ time ./test_rust < data.txt  > test3_res
io_time: 0, calc_time: 19

real    0m19.592s
user    0m19.560s
sys     0m0.020s
$ time ./test1 < data.txt  > test1_res

real    0m7.797s
user    0m7.780s
sys     0m0.010s
```

So it is at now ~ 2.7x difference on my [Core i7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i7).

Comment: The issue is most certainly that none of your implementations are equivalent. Write the Rust code exactly as the C++ version. Take a handle to stdout and stdin in the beginning of the application and lock them. Write directly to stdout's buffer instead of using the macro which incurs lock+formatting overhead.

Comment: Try building with `env RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=native" cargo build --release`. The Rust compiler refuses to use various higher end CPU extensions without specifically enabling them.

Comment: FWIW, `BufReader` is not ideal usage of `stdin`; try using `stdin.lock()` instead, which provides `BufRead` for you and avoids repeated locking. The difference isn't really meaningful, though, since IO isn't a large cost here.

Comment: @user1244932: I invite your to read the reddit discussion [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/4zx55q/xpost_stackoverflow_rust_version_is_4x_slower_as/), there were a number of comments that I personally found quite interesting and that are a bit too long to succinctly summarize :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The difference is of course `-march=native`... kind of. Rust has this through `-C target_cpu=native`, but this doesn't give the same speed benefit. This is because [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) is unwilling to vectorize in this context, whereas [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) does. You may note that using [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang), a C++ compiler that also uses LLVM, also produces relatively slow code.

To encourage LLVM to vectorize, you can move the main loop into a separate function. Alternatively, you can use a local block. If you write the code carefully as

```
let dist = {
    let mut dist = i32::max_value();
    for &(a, b) in &points_a[..n] {
        for &(c, d) in &points_b[..n] {
            dist = std::cmp::min(((a - c).abs() + (b - d).abs()), dist);
        }
    }
    dist
} as u32;
```

the difference between Rust and C++ is then near-negligible (~4%).

Answer (score 28):

The vast majority of the performance you're seeing in C++ is due to the flag `-march=native`.

This flag is not the equivalent flag to Rust's `--release`. It uses CPU instructions specific to the CPU it is compiled on, so math in particular is going to be *way* faster.

Removing that flag puts the C++ code at 19 seconds.

Then there's the unsafety present in the C++ code. None of the input is checked. The Rust code does check it, you use `.unwrap()` – `unwrap` has a performance cost, there's an assertion, then the code necessary for unwinding, etc.

Using `if let`s instead of raw `unwrap`s, or ignoring results where possible, brings the Rust code down again.

Rust: 22 seconds

C++: 19 seconds

Where's the 3 seconds coming from? A bit of playing around leads me to believe it's `println!` vs. `printf`, but I don't have hard numbers for the C++ code. What I can say is that the Rust code drops to 13 seconds when I perform the printing outside of the benchmark.

TLDR: Your compiler flags are different, and your C++ code is not safe.

Comment: `-march=native` is equivalent to `-C target-cpu=native`. Here are the times I get: C++: 12.417s; C++ with `-march=native`: 9.005s; Rust: 13.971s; Rust with `-C target-cpu=native`: 11.943s.

Comment: First of all it is not my `c++` code, I provided link in question where it came from.

Comment: Second I doubt that your finding about `println!` vs `printf` is correct. I implement `fast` variant of this algorithm with `O(N*log(N))` instead of `O(N * N)`, but leave input/output code `as is` and now result `0.7 seconds`, similar to what `fast c++` show. So input/output can not give more then `0.1 seconds`

Answer (score 2):

I'm definitely not seeing any difference in execution time. On my machine,

C++:

```
real    0m19.672s
user    0m19.636s
sys     0m0.060s
```

Rust:

```
real    0m19.047s
user    0m19.028s
sys     0m0.040s
```

I compiled the Rust code with `rustc -O test.rs -o ./test` and the C++ code with `g++ -Ofast test.cpp -o test`.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with Linux Kernel 4.6.3-040603-generic. The laptop I ran this on has an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU and 8GB of RAM, nothing special.

Comment: What versions do you use and how you run? I use rustc (1.12.0-beta.1) and gcc 5.3.0, and run with `time ./exe < data > /tmp/out`

Comment: rustc 1.13.0-nightly (e9bc1bac8 2016-08-24)

Comment: Also I run `cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/ && for i in `seq 0 7`; do echo performance > policy$i/scaling_governor; done` before timing measuring, did you do the same?

Comment: and g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: No, I didn't mess with my governor, but the governor would react within milliseconds, and the benchmark takes tens of seconds. At best, I would expect governor settings to make a few tenths of a second difference at best.

Comment: Huh. Running it with `-march=native` sped the C++ code up to the 6.7 seconds.

Comment: I rerun with `nightly`, instead of `beta` performance difference decrease from 4x to 2.7x

Comment: This looks like a very oddly specific set of circumstances that are allowing `native` to do real optimization. I've never heard of `-march=native` actually making such a difference before, and this only works with `g++`. The effect isn't nearly as dramatic with `clang++`, which shares the same backend as `rustc`.

Comment: I saw such effect with `icc` vs `gcc`. On simple matrix multiplication (1000x1000) icc speedup code by 10x, because of it can in such case do vectorization, while `gcc` can not.